# Venti fieldtype bug

Tags: fieldtypes, plugin-ventievents

I've added a Venti fieldtype to an entry and when I try to save it as an all-day event it says `Couldn't save entry`

```
Start Date and time must be set.
End Date and time must be set.
```

Help appreciated!

Comment: Hey Cole, please report this directly to the plugin developer. You can get in touch with them from the “Give Feedback/Get Help” link at the top-right of https://venti.helpdocs.com. Thanks!

Comment: Per your solution (below), it looks like this was a bug in the plugin. Please report the bug to the plugin developers through their proper channels. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks - have done. Posted answer here in case anybody else was experiencing a similar issue

Answer (score 1):

Have managed to resolve by updating the `_convertTimes` function in `venti/fieldtypes/Venti_EventFieldType.php`.

Change (line 141):

```
if ((is_string($value['startDate']) && $value['startDate']) || (is_array($value['startDate']) && $value['startDate']['time']))
```

To:

```
if ((is_string($value['startDate']) && $value['startDate']) || (is_array($value['startDate']) && $value['startDate']['time']) || (is_array($value['startDate']) && $value['allDay'] == 1 && $value['startDate']['date']))`
```

And (line 150):

```
if ((is_string($value['endDate']) && $value['endDate']) || (is_array($value['endDate']) && $value['endDate']['time']))
```

To:

```
if ((is_string($value['endDate']) && $value['endDate']) || (is_array($value['endDate']) && $value['endDate']['time']) || (is_array($value['endDate']) && $value['allDay'] == 1 && $value['endDate']['date']))
```

This will remove the need to add a time if an all day event is specified.